# The term "My best to you" at the end of an email

Tags: meaning, email, valediction

What does the above mean?  A form of goodbye?  Or the best to you until we speak or communicate again? Best wishes? A male acquaintance wrote this at the end of his email when responding to my email.We do not communicate everyday because he has busy career. He knows I have experienced tough times.

Comment: I'd say it means 'I'm sending you my best wishes'.

Answer (score 2):

It means "best wishes" and has a few variants:

> Best wishes
>
> My best to you
>
> My very best
>
> I wish you the best

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

It does mean literally "I'm giving you my best wishes," but it's a formality like "Sincerely yours."  Idiomatically it can mean anything from "I'm giving you my best wishes" to "I'm politely ending this letter now."

Answer (score -1):

In my experience it means they don't expect or want to hear from you again so they are saying good luck and goodbye.

Answer (score -3):

It means - With my best intentions

Comment: Other answerers and commenters have indicated that the phrase "My best to you"  means "My best wishes to you." Can you point to any reference authorities that support your contention that it means "With my best intentions"? If you can, please do so.

Comment: Although I disagree with @Sven's assertion that this is wrong, -1 for not answering the question.  (Unfortunately higher voted answers don't either, except for user139504 who at least understood the question but reaches a questionable conclusion)